# Accessing UIViewController components within subviews (array) of UIStackView

Tags: ios, swift

first of all, this is my first time to post a question in Stack Overflow.

So...

Currently, I have a custom textfield that I create on separate nib file called FormTextField:

```
class FormTextField: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var labelTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        labelTitle.textColor = UIColor.red
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```

Then, in the main layout, I have a UIStackView, and I load the FormTextField based on passenger count:

```
for view in stackViewOrdering.arrangedSubviews {
    stackViewOrdering.removeArrangedSubview(view)
    view.removeFromSuperview()
}

name.removeAll()
for ordering in 1...(data.qty ?? 0) {
    let item = FormTextField(nibName: "FormTextField", bundle: nil)
    _ = item.view
    item.labelTitle.text = "Passenger Name \(ordering.toString())"
    item.textField.placeholder = "Put your name"
    item.textField.tag = ordering
    item.textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onTextChanged(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
    name.append("")
    stackViewOrdering.addArrangedSubview(item.view)
}


@objc func onTextChanged(_ textField: UITextField) {
    name[textField.tag - 1] = textField.text ?? ""
    validate()
}
```

Then, I have an idea to make a button that when user click on it. The first FormTextField automatically will be filled by his/her name. I've tried to create this code, but it didn't work:

```
if let iv = stackViewOrdering.arrangedSubviews[0] as? FormTextField {
    iv.textField.text = active ? (user.fullName ?? "") : ""
    name[0] = active ? (user.fullName ?? "") : ""
    validate()
}
```

There is a warning that says: **"Cast from 'UIView' tp unrelated type 'FormTextField' always fails"**

I've tried to change the FormTextField type to UIView, but it still didn't worked, and I can handle the validation when user has or has not filled the text field.

Thank in advance!

Comment: You definitely need FormTextField to be a UIView in this particular scenario, so do that and if it still doesn't work, please update with the error you get then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, welcome to SO.

Your implementation has several issues.

1.Your `FormTextField` it's a subclass of `UIViewController` and you're not using it properly. You are using the view of the `FormTextField` but you're not adding the actual `FormTextField` as a child view controller to any `UIVIewController`. The proper way of adding a `UIViewController` as child is like this:

```
var controller: FormTextField = // do the nib load here
controller.willMoveToParentViewController(self)
stackViewOrdering.addSubview(controller.view)
self.addChildViewController(controller)
controller.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

2.When you try to validate you are trying to cast a `UIView` to `FormTextField`, keep in mind that your `stackViewOrdering` holds instances of `UIView` and not `FormTextField` because you did `stackViewOrdering.addSubview(controller.view)`

Now that I've shown you the issues, you can fix them in several ways:

1.If you want to keep the `FormTextField` as subclass of `UIViewController` then you should do something like this:

````
if let controller = self.children[0] as? ```FormTextField``` {
    controller.textField // do whatever you want here.
}
````

2.The best way to do it, in my opinion, is to change `FormTextField` to be subclass of `UIView` and not `UIViewController`. For this you'll have to change the way you load the view from nib (there's a lot of samples on the internet on how to do it). If you do this, your code will work as it is, the only line that has to be changed is:

`let item = FormTextField(nibName: "FormTextField", bundle: nil)`

Comment: Yes! thank you for suggesting. I change the FormTextField to UIView. Then, everything was ok, thanks you so much!

Comment: @PaterMhd If my answer helped you make sure to mark it as the correct one. It might help other devs too :)